# C#: is there a way to make the creation of getters and setters automatic?

Tags: c#, properties

I'm writing a Mongo web application using their official C# driver.

In order to implement references, they have to be fetched manually.

so let's say we have

```
class User {
    ...
    public MongoDBRef Topic { get; set; }
}
```

To fetch the topic we need to do the following:

```
db.FetchDBRefAs<Topic>(user.Topic);
```

And to create a new one:

```
user.Topic = new MongoDBRef(TopicsTable, topic._id);
```

I decided to create a virtual property to make it more convenient:

```
    [BsonIgnore]
    public Topic _Topic
    {
        get
        {
            return db.FetchDBRefAs<Topic>(Topic);
        }
        set
        {
            CreatedAd = new MongoDBRef(TopicsTable, value._id);
        }
    }
```

Now I can use it like this:

```
 user._Topic = someTopic;
 anotherTopic = user._Topic;
```

Obviously it's a big pain to do this for all referenced objects.

Is there a way to make this process automatic?

Thanks

Comment: You're not using the correct terminology. That is not a "virtual property". A "virtual property" would actually have the `virtual` keyword in it: `public virtual Topic _Topic {...}`, and it would mean it could be overridden in derived classes. That is simply a "explicitly implemented property", or a "manual property", as opposed to "auto-property".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [Visual Studio code snippets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165392.aspx), I suspect. I've never done so myself, but I think this is precisely the sort of thing they're normally used for.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Visual Studio code snippets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165392.aspx).

Type in `prop` and two tabs, and you just need to fill in the type and name of the property.

There are built in snippets for a full property with backing field (`propfull`), read-only property (`propg`) and many more things - for example an empty constructor (`ctor`).

You can also create and use your own code snippets.